# Как организовать "переползание" элементов

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно чтобы все элементы как бы переползали в одну линию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы раскрыть свой вопрос так, чтобы и другим людям тоже стало понятно, в чем именно у вас проблема, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что и куда должно переползти? Задайте вопрос так, чтобы понятно было не только Вам.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решается созданием нужной разметки (xml файл). Для этого Вы должны изучить разные виды разметки. Если нужно "навсегда" изменить разметку - то вопрос прост. Если по какому-то событию необходимо изменить разметку, то тут уже возможны варианты: 1. Менять разметку кодом. 2. Загружать другой фрагмент/окно с нужной разметкой.